# Bash bad substitution when trying to uppercase first letter

Tags: bash

I am banging my head against the wall about the `Bad substitution` error in Bash. Consider the following code:

```sh
getApiName() {
    IFS='-' # hyphen (-) is set as delimiter
        read -ra array <<< "$1" # str is read into an array as tokens separated by IFS
        for i in "${array[@]}"; do # access each element of array
            output+=${i^} #set first letter to uppercase
        done
    IFS=' '
    echo ${output}
}
```

When I do the following:

```sh
getApiName "vl-date-picker"
```

I get `line 21: ${i^}: bad substitution`

I have no clue on what's wrong.
Can you guys help me please?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: You sure you're running this on bash?

Comment: Yes, via an npm run script though

Comment: I don't know about npm, but this works on my bash. Make sure it is bash and not sh

Comment: @Homewrecker: What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` output, when executed inside your script (not on your command line)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General Answer

I cannot reproduce your problem. I see two possible reasons:

- **You are using a non-bash shell.**
  Check this by adding the command `ps` to the script and look at the output. If there is no `bash` in the output, then you are running something different. A shebang  `#! /bin/bash` at the beginning of your script helps to ensure that `bash` is used but is not a guarantee. ✱
- **You have an old version of bash which does not support `${i^}`

  (for instance that 15 (!) year old version pre-installed on Mac OS X)**.
  You can check your bash version using `bash --version`. `${i^}` was introduced in bash 4.0, as can be read [here](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) (search for `hh. There are new case-modifying word expansions`) or [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061).

Either way, you can use a different command which should work in all Posix shells.

If you have the GNU version of `sed` (check with `sed --version`) this command could be

```
getApiName() {
    printf %s "$1" | sed -E 's/(^|-+)(.)/\U\2/g'
}
```

## Nmp-Specific Answer

✱
The [documentation of `npm-run-script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) states

> The actual shell your script is run within is platform dependent. By default, on Unix-like systems it is the /bin/sh command, on Windows it is the cmd.exe. The actual shell referred to by /bin/sh also depends on the system. As of npm@5.1.0 you can customize the shell with the script-shell configuration.

So to fix your problem you simply have to configure npm such that `bash` is used instead.

As a workaround, you could also call `bash` directly in your script. The simplest way to do so is a here-document:

```
bash -s -- "$@" <<"EOF"
    # your original script here
EOF
```

Comment: Adding ps to the script showed me that, however the shebang line is present, the script is run as sh.
`75493 ttys001    0:00.00 sh -c . ./scripts/updateReadme.sh`. I will have to figure out how to force NPM to use bash.